# MEAN-Stack -- GET http://localhost:3000/api/test net::ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE

Tags: node.js, express, httprequest, mean-stack, angular-httpclient

I am a newbie in MEAN-Stack developing and need your help.
When I try a http get/post request using the Angular httpClient, I keep getting the following error message ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE.
I start calling my get method within my frontend folder test.service.ts:

```
getTests(){
this.http 
.get<{message: string, tests: TestModel[]}>('http://localhost:3000/api/test') 
.subscribe((_testData)=>{ 
  console.log(_testData); 
}); 
}
```

The above used TestModel is my data model used in frontend:

```
export interface TestModel { 
id: string; 
title: string; }
```

Within my backend folder, my folder structure looks like in the picture attached. [folder structure backend](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aExwG.png)

This is how my app.js looks like (i replaced line 12, but the connection to database works).

```
const express = require('express')
const mongoose = require("mongoose");
const bodyParser = require("body-parser");
const test = require("./routing/test");
const app = express();
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
   
mongoose
  .connect(
    x
  )
  .then(() => {
    console.log("Connected to database!");
  })
  .catch(() => {
    console.log("Connection failed!");
  });

//https://www.javatpoint.com/cors-in-mean-stack 
app.use((req, res, next) => {
  res.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
  res.setHeader(
    "Access-Control-Allow-Headers",
    "Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept, Authorization");
  res.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Methods","GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS");
  next();
});

app.use("/api/test", test); 
module.exports = app;
```

My test.js where i expect the error origin looks as follows:

```
const express = require("express"); 
const testModel = require('../models/testModel'); 
const router = express.Router();
router.get("",(req,res,next)=>{
  const testRooms = [
    {
      id: "1",
      title: "1"
    },
    {
      id: "2",
      title:"2"
    },
  ]
  return res.json("testMessage", testRooms);
});

module.exports = router;
```

And finally my backend data model:

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const express = require("express");
const router = express.Router()

const TestSchema = mongoose.Schema({
  id: {type: String, required: true, unique: true},
  title: {type: String, required: true},
});

module.exports = mongoose.model('TestSchema', TestSchema);
```

My server.js (which refers to the app.js) should work correctly, therefore I haven't posted it here.

It seems like the http module is not able to access the node backend at all, since I get the same error message if I delete the method in the "test.js". First google result hinted that this might be a CORS issue, but I don't think that this is the case here.
I am quite lost :((
If I missed to upload or mention something, just let me know.

Thanks a lot for any help and a happy new year's eve :)

Comment: `try router.get("/") router.get("") seems invalid to me ... (I might be wrong though)`

Comment: thanks @anees ! I just tried it, unfortunately still the same result :/ will try again tomorrow